# The order of the link element (for external css) and the internal css shouldn't matter, should they?

Tags: css, external, internals

I know that if we use internal css and external css at the same time (on the same selector) then the internal style should take higher priority and overwrites the external style. However, I ran into a problem here and couldn't figure out why.

I have following style definition in the head element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<style type="text/css">
    h2 {font-family: verdana; color: red;}
</style>enter code here
```

In styles.css I have

```
h2 {color: blue;}
```

Then the styles work as they should -- the h2 element is in red.

But if I put the link element after the internal styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h2 {font-family: verdana; color: red;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

then the cascading rule is not working anymore -- the h2 is blue instead of red, which means external style now has higher priority than the internal one.

It doesn't make sense but I couldn't figure out why. Could anyone enlighten me on this? TIA.

Comment: Is it not because the stylesheet is loaded after the internal styles? I actually never heard of internal 'stronger' than external styles. Only inline styles are different than external styles.

Comment: As above, CSS files are applied in the order they are defined in the page.  If 20 files all have the same specificity and target the same element (eg: an `H2` element), then the last loaded file will take priority.

Answer (score 1):

This is working exactly as intended if you link it this way. The style that comes later will override the earlier style. (If the selectors are EXACTLY the same).

By "internal" you may mean "inline" styles, which do have priority and will override any other styles.

Example:

```
<h2 style="color: orange">Hello world</h2>
```

This "inline style rule" will override most other rules, although there are ways to override this as well.

For more information, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). There is also a very handy [reference chart](https://specifishity.com/).

Comment: Faster than me :)

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is correct, cause your "internal style" is not an inline style, it considered at the same level of an external css file.

In your second example:
First your browser read first rule (h2 { color: red} ) and then it overrides that rule with the one inside the style.css

This is the expected behaviour.

But in case in your code you'll write an inline style like:

```
<h2 style='color: yellow'>This text will be yellow</h2>
```

then this rule will overrides the first two rules.

"Cascading" means the last rule read will overrides the first.

Comment: I think you explained it better :)